# "Would draw" with "Can't draw"

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Folks, I would like to know if an effect like "players can't draw cards" prevents/cancel effects like "if you would draw a card, instead do X".

Because I wouldn't draw a card anyway, the effect does not takes place?

For a concrete example, think on [Maralen of the Mornsong](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152546) with [Forbidden Crypt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForbidden%20Crypt%5d).

Comment: I'm almost sure nothing happens (the effect does not takes place), I just want to confirm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ruling on Maralen seems to support your conclusion that nothing happens:

> 4/1/2008: While Maralen is on the battlefield, replacement effects that instruct a player to do something instead of drawing a card won't work.

Answer (score 8):

Can't beats can. So when something tells you to draw a card (say the beginning of your draw step), and Maralen telling you that you can't draw cards you do not get to draw a card. Since you are not drawing a card the Crypt's replacement effect doesn't have a chance to apply.

> **101.2.** When a rule or effect allows or directs something to happen, and another effect states that it can’t happen, the “can’t” effect takes precedence.
>
> **614.7.** If a replacement effect would replace an event, but that event never happens, the replacement effect simply doesn’t do anything.